# python plot with matplotlib a json file data

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have the following json file and I would like to make bar graphs based on bytes and timestamp. Noticed timestamps provided on the file are not in order, and they need to .

```
{
    "success":true,
        "data":[
            {

                "record_id":258585618,
                "timestamp":"2018-01-21 22:34:34",
                "bytes":29466,

            }
            ,
            {
                "record_id":258585604,
                "timestamp":"2018-01-21 22:33:14",
                "bytes":37892,
            }
            ,
            {
                "record_id":258584399,
                "timestamp":"2018-01-21 22:37:40",
                "bytes":36396,
            }
        ]
    }
```

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: I have now sorted the dates for the bar graph.

You could do something like this:

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
data = json.dumps({
    "success":True,
        "data":[
            {

                "record_id":258585618,
                "timestamp":"2018-01-21 22:34:34",
                "bytes":29466,

            }
            ,
            {
                "record_id":258585604,
                "timestamp":"2018-01-21 22:33:14",
                "bytes":37892,
            }
            ,
            {
                "record_id":258584399,
                "timestamp":"2018-01-21 22:37:40",
                "bytes":36396,
            }
        ]
    })

data = json.loads(data)
dates = [i['timestamp'] for i in data["data"]]
values = [i['bytes'] for i in data['data']]

df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':dates, 'values':values})
df['dates']  = [pd.to_datetime(i) for i in df['dates']]

print(df.sort_values(by='dates'))

                dates  values
1 2018-01-21 22:33:14   37892
0 2018-01-21 22:34:34   29466
2 2018-01-21 22:37:40   36396

plt.bar(dates, values)
```

[image]

Comment: i just noticed that you need the time stamps to be ordered, should they also be the x-axis labels?

Comment: I think it is a cosmetic thing, but it would be appreciated if it can be also implemented.